# How to delete all the data from a table after 5 seconds using Laravel Query Builder?

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

I have this query

```
$data = DB::table('incidencias')
    ->select(DB::raw("STR_TO_DATE(fecha_notif, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s') as time"))
    ->get();

    $data = json_decode(json_encode($data, true), true);

    DB::table('incidencia_tiempo')->insert($data);
```

I would like to delete all the data from the table only one time after run the query.... for example if I refresh, the data will be deleted after 5 seconds, with one time is enough... is it posible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To **delete all data in a table**, it's as simple as doing

```
DB::table('incidencias')->truncate()
```

or

```
DB::table('incidencias')->delete();
```

---

## Update

If you want to delete the data **after** 5 seconds have passed, then you can just do:

```
sleep(5)
DB::table('incidencias')->delete();
```

### Refresh using Javascript

Your controller:

```
public function deleteAll()
{
    DB::table('incidencias')->truncate();

    if (request()->ajax()) {
        return response()->json(['success' => true]);
    }
    
    return back(); // if not ajax...
}
```

Your HTML

```
// For example, deleting it all every 5 seconds AFTER the delete button is pressed
<button id="delete">Delete all</button>

<script>
    $('#delete').click(function () {
        // in this case start deleting when you click this delete button only once..
        startDeleting();
    });

    // the actual code that does the GET request to the URL every 5 seconds
    function startDeleting() {
        setInterval(function () {
            // Submit as post/get depending on your route config.
            $.ajax({
                url: "/your-url-to-controller", success: function (result) {
                    // what to do if we get success (if you wanna do anything)
                    console.log(result);
                }
            });
        }, 5000); // time in milliseconds
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I would like to delete all the data from the table only one time after run the query.... for example if I refresh, the data will be deleted after 5 seconds, with one time is enough... is it posible?

Comment: Please check my updated answer to delete after 5 seconds, from what I understand

Comment: thanks for your answer, with this the page keeps updating for 5 seconds... I would like to delete the table 5 seconds after the update of the page

Comment: Are you open to using Javascript?

Comment: Please check the updated way, it should give you an idea of how to proceed.

Comment: bless you!! tanks a lot my friend!!

Comment: ey bro!! your code works and it deletes the table but I got this in my browser ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.. you know why?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, were you able to figure it out? If not, I think it's due to the redirection returned from the controller.